# Keep custom functions aligned with their source files

Tags: ms-office, office-js, custom-functions-excel

In [this link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions), it says that

> During development and testing, you can manually clear your computer's cache of registration metadata by deleting the folder `<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\CustomFunctio‌​ns`.

I then make a test as follows:

1. I load a `manifest.xml` pointing to the original `customfunctions.js` in my server in a workbook. After closing the workbook, a file is automatically saved in `...\Wef\CustomFunctio‌​ns\V1`.
2. I modify manually `customfunctions.js` in my server by replacing `Excel.Script.CustomFunctions["CONTOSO"]["ADD42"]` by `Excel.Script.CustomFunctions["CONTOSO"]["ADD42NEW"]`.
3. I open a new workbook, in a cell, after enter `=contoso.`, the IntelliSense shows me `contoso.add42` rather than `add42new`. After entering `=contoso.add42(5;4)`, the cells shows `#GETTING_DATA` and does not return a value. That's understandable because it works on a function which does not exist anymore.
4. If we click on another cell and enter e.g., `=2+3`, we see the workbook is refreshed, and `#GETTING_DATA` becomes `#NAME?`. And now IntelliSense shows `contoso.add42new` rather than `contoso.add42`.

To conclude, I think there may be a bug: when we open a workbook, IntelliSense should give the updated list of custom functions defined in the current `customfunctions.js`.

Actually, what is ideal is that the custom functions in workbook always keep aligned with what are defined in `customfunctions.js`. If there was not this bug, today we still needed to close a workbook and reopen one to get updated. Does anyone know if there is a workaround to make custom functions in an opened workbook keep updated on the fly? Is there a refreshing trigger that allows us to make custom functions in an opened workbook update from the current `customfunctions.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the question! As you've discovered, custom function definitions are currently updated only on-demand rather than on every single document-open event.

We've received a bunch of feedback in this area and so we're considering some changes to how registration works so that the list of functions in IntelliSense/autocomplete gets updated at the beginning of a session instead of in the middle of one.

I don't have details to share right now, but be on the lookout for some changes here in a few months.